# password manager increasing size password every time

Tags: c++

I am creating a password manager , but my password manager is generating the password every 3s , but however it is also increasing its size every load. how can I keep its fixed lenght ? on the other side my function `randomString it has setSeed` which is for randomize , but it also keep the the same password every 3s

```
int main() {
    std::string t = reverse.ascii_lowercase() + reverse.ascii_uppercase() + reverse.digits() + reverse.punctuation();
    std::vector<std::string> random_keys;
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        std::cout << "1s" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            random_keys.push_back(reverse.randomString(15, t));
        std::cout << reverse.join(random_keys, "--");
    }
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

seed

```
void Common::setSeed() {
    static bool set = false;

    if (!set)
    {
        srand(time(NULL));
        set = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really hope this is for academic purposes only because seeing `srand(time(NULL))` in here is somewhat concerning where passwords are involved.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using [`rand()` is highly problematic](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) and you’re strongly encouraged to use an appropriate [random number generator facility in the Standard Library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that produces high-quality random values. Your use of `time(NULL)` as a random number seed means that this will produce identical results if run in the same second, and on many platforms `rand()` is [*barely* random at all](http://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25).

Comment: it is academic purposes , but everytime if passwd is 5 the next time is 10 and so on , but it also keep the same password everytime.

Comment: There appears to be a lot of code missing here. What is `reverse`? As a general note you should try and keep your `main` function as simple as possible, focus on delegating to functions with meaningful names where the real work happens.

Comment: Seems like you never clear out `random_keys` Maybe that's why?

Comment: in a code level how can I clear out  random_keys ? , and reverse is a variable from class name

Comment: You can move that vector definition inside the loop, for example. That'll do it. You'll get a new vector for each iteration.

Comment: in the case of rand() . should I remove every rand function by mt19937 ?

Comment: Throw `rand()` into the sun and never use it again. C++ has a fantastic [random number generation system](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) that you should be using exclusively. There's many different tools there, so saying which one works in your case depends on how random you need. For passwords I'd say use the most raw, actually random data, not pseudo-random at all like the Mersenne Twister provides (mt).

Comment: how example  the most raw for you ? which one?

Comment: Like [`std::random_device`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/random_device) which is slower but very random. That is *usually but not always* random. You can also make use of OS level facilities (e.g. `/dev/random`) if necessary.

Comment: What is `reverse` in your code?   It is rather central to the working of your code - presumably producing the string for each iteration - and you have provided no information about it whatsoever.   Read up on providing a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're not resetting that vector, so the solution may be as simple as moving it inside the loop:

```
while (true) {
    std::vector<std::string> random_keys; // New vector for each iteration

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    std::cout << "1s" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        random_keys.push_back(reverse.randomString(15, t));
    std::cout << reverse.join(random_keys, "--");
}
```